# Jetifier failed to transform

Tags: android, react-native, androidx, android-jetifier

This error occured after I upgraded my react-native to 0.59 version and applied the jetifier for for new updates.

```
Execution failed to transform for task ':app:javaPrecompileDebug' Failed to transform 
'localSDK.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: Method code too large!. (Run with --stacktrace for more details).
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use it on gradle.properties

```
android.enableJetifier=false
```